# How are armlocks categorised in Judo?

Tags: judo, terminology, joint-lock

I had always thought that the distinction between *ude-garami* and *ude-hishigi-...-gatame* was that the former referred to bent arm figure-four elbow/shoulder locks and the latter referred to armbars (applied in various ways).

However the [*Kodokan Judo Katame-Waza Techniques*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM) video demonstrates multiple examples of armbars (that I would previously have called *ude-hishigi-ude-gatame*) in its section on [*ude-garami*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=100):

[image] [image]

It seems that it is implying the defining point of ude-garami is the figure-four position of *tori's* arms, not the mechanics of the pressure applied to uke's joints.

Is this accurate? If not, how are armlocks categorised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Kodokan classifies armlocks according to the position *tori* adopts while applying them.

As such this lock (sometimes called [*kannuki-gatame*](https://judoinfo.com/kansetsuwaza/)) is indeed a variant of *ude-garami*, since tori holds uke's arm in place with an "entangled" figure-four position.<sup>2</sup>

This methodology for classifying armlocks can be seen in the other examples in the same video:

#### 1. Same biomechanics, different names

The Kodokan gives different names to an armbar<sup>1</sup> depending on which part of the body tori uses as a fulcrum/to secure the lock, despite them all attacking the same joint in the same direction:

- *ude-hishigi-juji-gatame*
- *ude-hishigi-ude-gatame*
- *ude-hishigi-hiza-gatame*
- *ude-hishigi-waki-gatame*

#### 2. Different biomechanics, same name

Contrastingly, the Kodokan gives multiple different types of joint-lock (e.g. hyper-extending the elbow, abducting the bent elbow, hyper-rotating the shoulder) the same name, determined by the body parts tori uses to control uke's arm/as a fulcrum for the lock:

- *Te-gatame* refers to:

  1. [armbars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=1280), where uke's arm is held in position with both hands
  2. [hammerlocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=1381), where the shoulder joint is hyper-rotated by holding uke's arm bent against their back with the hands
  3. [bent elbow-locks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=1406), secured with only one hand (instead of two in a figure-four position as in *ude-garami*)
- *Ude-hishigi-hiza-gatame* refers to both:

  1. armbars secured with tori's knee
  2. [bent elbow-locks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=849) (hyper-abduction) using the knee as a fulcrum
- *Ude-hishigi-hara-gatame* refers to both:

  1. armbars applied at the waist
  2. [bent elbow-locks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=1093) using the waist to trap the joint/as a fulcrum
- *Ude-hishigi-sankaku-gatame* refers to both:

  1. armbars applied from a triangle
  2. [bent elbow-locks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHJ1M3htDnM&t=1490) applied from a triangle

---

**Notes:**

<sup>1. armbar  = straight elbow-lock = hyper-extension of the elbow-joint</sup>

<sup>2. Given the wide array of joint-locks which fall under the blanket of *ude-garami*, one may wish to distinguish the variants further with more specific (non-Kodokan) names:</sup>
<sup>• normal ude-garami (**ab**ducts elbow, laterally hyperrotates shoulder)

• reverse ude-garami (**ad**ducts elbow, medially hyperrotates shoulder)

• kannuki-gatame (hyperextends elbow)</sup>

Comment: Anatomical movement terminology: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-ap/chapter/mapping-the-body/